# Convert const char* string to NSString with length AND encoding

Tags: c++, cocoa, encoding, objective-c++

I wonder which method would be better to convert const char* string to NSString.
I found there are some facts.

- [NSString stringWithCString:length:] is kind of deprecated.
- [NSString stringWithCString:encoding] may be used for my purpose

But I want to convert with length AND encoding(because I want to make that fine if I have some Non-ASCII character by setting encoding to UTF-8). Any thoughts?

I just think now

1. create other char and copy with length by using std::strncpy(ch1, ch2, len)
2. use [NSString stringWithCString:encoding:]

But it doesn't work well.

Answer (score 45):

If your const char* variable is named `foo` (and it points to a null-terminated string), just say

```
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:foo]
```

Because UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII, this will work whether `foo` points to UTF-8 or ASCII. Then you can move up to full Unicode with no problems.

Comment: This only works if your string is ASCII, though. If your string is anything else (e.g. MacRoman or ISO Latin), you'll at best get the wrong glyph displayed for a particular character, at worst you'll get a NIL string because you happened to generate an invalid sequence of bytes that doesn't map to a valid UTF8 character (Yes, that's possible. UTF8 encodes way more than 256 different characters, so there are multi-byte sequences that encode a character, and some of these aren't valid (yet).

Answer (score 17):

Use:

```
[NSString initWithBytes:length:encoding].
```